# variable name as macro argument

Tags: c, c11

I am trying to create a macro in c, that will take a variable name, and declare it. I could call it like this:

```
MY_MACRO(test);
```

Would produce:

```
int test;
```

In order to achieve this I went this way:

```
#define MY_MACRO(var)   /
    int ##var;          /
```

But the compiler doesn't understand this. Does such syntax exist in C11?

Comment: Simply `#define MY_MACRO(var) int var`. No semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing such a thing. Anyway, there are two problems. First of all, to skip a newline, you need `\`, not `/`.

Second, the `##` is wrong. What it does is concatenating the `var` to the `int`. So with `MY_MACRO(foo)` you would get `intfoo;`, but you want `int foo;`

The macro needs to be like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO(var)   \
int var
```

Comment: What about `MY_MACRO(a) = 5;` ?

Comment: @Blaze thanks for answer. The slash mismatch is my obvious mistake, sorry. I am trying to implement a smart pointer mechanism in C, this is just the beginning of it. The macro will have more than 1 line.

Answer (score 2):

`##` is not applicable here as it concatenates the token with something else

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MY_MACRO(var) int var
```

or

```
#define MY_MACRO(var) \
int var          \
```

---

```
void foo(void)
{
    MY_MACRO(a);

    a = rand();

    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`##` pastes two tokens together into one token.

```
#define poem(var)\
    int jack##var;

// Produces 'int jacksprat;'
poem(sprat)
```

In your case you don't need to do anything special at all, you can just use the argument directly:

```
#define MY_MACRO(var)\
    int var;
```

Comment: What about `MY_MACRO(a) = 5;` ?

Comment: @P__J__ What about it? OP wanted to expand to a declaration without initialiser.

Comment: `;` in macros == bad idea

Answer (score 0):

The [correct syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments) would be something along the lines of this:

```
#define MY_MACRO(ident) \
    int ident

int main() {
    MY_MACRO(test);
    test =42;
    return test;
}
```

However, have you been looking into [typedefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)? Unlike typedefs, macros are considered bad practice.

Comment: @P__J__ This is a case of "fastest gun in the west". There's only minutes between when the various answers were posted.

Comment: The others weren't there when I started writing it and there would be no use in removing it now. And I'm surprised I'm the only one to have mentioned typedefs